# Command not found

Tags: rhel, command, services

I am trying to stop a syslog using **chkconfig** but bash says that command is not available. But when I do

> man chkconfig

it opens man page.

This is the command i'm trying to execute.

```
**chkconfig syslog off && /etc/init.d/syslog stop**
```

[image: Screen Cap]

Comment: Which distribition are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot 
686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
Version 5.5

.It is installed on virtual Box and Host OS ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @UmairMustafa Please add such information to your question instead by editing it. That way people will spot it easier and it will not disappear among comments.

Comment: output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: @warl0ck    /usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/Umair/bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have chkconfig in your $PATH,

If you get your root prompt through `su`, try `su -` instead.

But anyway, `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin` will fix this issue